# IntegrityError at /add/ NOT NULL constraint failed: myApp_bookdetail.manager_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having IntegrityError at /add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: myApp_bookdetail.manager_id

```
class BookDetail(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inum = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Did you migrate your database after adding  `null=True`?

Comment: Try removing the most previous migrations and then run migrate command again.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `form.save` then here's my answer. Whenever there's a `ForeignKey` in your model, then directly saving the model using `form.save()` causes this error. So this is how we save models with `ForeignKey`-

```py
book = form.save(commit = False)
book.manager = request.user
book.save()
```

Comment: And you can also just remove `default = None` and `null = True`,  it would still work